# Securely sending password data to REST API?

Tags: django, rest, security, ssl, django-rest-framework

I have a REST API made with Django Rest Framework. 
This API has an endpoint for creating new users. When creating a new user, I obviously need to provide some sort of password. What I am concerned about is how to communicate that password data from the client to the create user endpoint in the API via JSON. 
 Do I send the password in plain text? Should I encrypt client side and then send? SSL/HTTPS? 
 TL;DR: How do I safely do something like this: POST to myapi.com/create-user with_data {'password':'my password'}

Comment: @dgel great, thanks. Can you move this to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending in plain text over HTTPS would be just as secure as any other web account creation you've done from the browser.

Although you don't actually *need* to require the user provide a password- you could have them provide an email and you dynamically create a temporary password and email it to them.

Comment: Just realize that most email communication is highly insecure. Unless you're sending out encrypted email, better stick to letting the user pick a password.